# Bing speech API constantly returns ServiceUnavailable status

Tags: c#, bing, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

I am trying to use the Bing Speech Api using C# but 95% of the times I get the following response from the API:

> Message=SendRequest: Non-success status received :: Status Code:
>   ServiceUnavailable; Reason: ; Content: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>body
>   { font-family:Arial; margin-left:40px; }img  { border:0 none;
>   }#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }#logo { margin-top:
>   30px; width=120px; height=34px }#message h2 { font-size: 20px;
>   font-weight: normal; color: #000000; margin: 34px 0px 0px 0px
>   }#message p  { font-size: 13px; color: #000000; margin: 7px 0px 0px
>   0px }#errorref { font-size: 11px; color: #737373; margin-top: 41px
>   }Bing
>
> ### Bing services aren't available right now
>
> We're
>   working to restore all services as soon as possible.
> We know you
>   want to get back to searching. Please check back soon.
>
> Ref A: A1C0134338234D4AA480524F216CB616 Ref B:
>   PAR02EDGE0112 Ref C:
>   2018-09-27T17:12:16Z

I do have a valid key and I am succesfully authenticated by the API, at first I thought that the servers were down but I'm getting the same response since one week so I assume something else is wrong.

Any insight would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I am communicating with the api through an open source C# library (https://github.com/NateRickard/Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech). 
The endpoint I am using is the default one in the library, "speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition".

Here is an overview of the request which is sent through HTTP:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=fr-FR&format=simple&profanity=masked', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.PushStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Expect: 100-continue
  Accept: application/json
  Accept: text/xml
  Host: speech.platform.bing.com
  Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {my subscription key}
  Content-Type: audio/wav
}}
```

Comment: Can you add more details about the way you are calling the API (code sample, endpoints, etc)

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more detailed information.

Comment: Is this error coming back immediately or could it be timing out?

Comment: No, the response of the API is never coming immediately (if I specify an invalid subscription key it does though), there is a slight delay of roughly 3 seconds.

Comment: Did you solved that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it worked for me with python if I use the following header (instead of your header):

```
url = 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/dictation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=detailed'

header = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': YOUR_API_KEY,
    'Content-type': 'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=audiodata)
```